# ROC curve and optimal threshold

Tags: classification

I am doing a practice problem predicting a binary outcome. I have plotted an ROC curve and found the optimal threshold percentage to call future predicted observations a 1. I see that this threshold always matches the percentage of observations equal to 1 in my original data. Is there any conceptual explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that this threshold always matches the percentage of observations equal to 1 in my original data. Is there any conceptual explanation for this?

Yes, although the fact it always matches *exactly* is probably a coincidence or maybe due to a small sample.

The training data contains a proportion $p$ of instances labelled 1. From the ROC plot you can see all the possible values for setting the threshold at a certain level and the resulting performance; for every possible level you can calculate the corresponding proportion $q$ of instances predicted as 1:

- if $q$ is much lower than $p$, then the system predicts many 0s, so there are many false negative errors and that makes the recall lower. Precision is high in this case.
- if $q$ is much higher than $p$, then the system predicts many 1s, so there are many false positive errors and that makes the precision lower. Recall is high in this case.

I assume that you optimize on the F1-score right? The fact that the F1-score is based on the product of the precision and recall means that **both** values need to be reasonably high, otherwise the F1-score drops. As seen above, having very different values for $p$ and $q$ will cause either the precision or recall to be low. Therefore the optimal F1-score is achieved when $q$ is close to $p$.